# Excel VBA - Import Sections of Textfile (Binary Import)

Tags: vba, excel

First time posting - please be gentle :)

I have a large text file (around 50MB) that sits on our work server. The file is sorted by a key in ascending order. I was wondering if it's possible to search and import the section of the file that matches the key using a binary search.

For example, the code will take 512kb of the file and see if the data I need is in that part of the file, if not, move to the next 512kb until it finds the data we need. Also, the key will have several rows (2K) of data, so the code will need to look for the start and end point of the key.

I'm hoping to save time when loading the file by only loading the section of the file that has the data the user needs. There is a new file produced every hour with the latest data, and due to the server being slow (expecially when connecting remotly (i.e. working from home) it currently takes a long time to load the whole file into the report.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to load only that part of the file which you are interested in. This is mainly due to the fact that you cannot tell where to start looking in the file. What would you want to write? Start looking in the 50MB file around the 12MB position?

Yet, you could read the file line by line without having to load the entire file into memory first:

```
Public Sub ImportToExcel()

Dim intCounter As Long
Dim intPointer As Integer
Dim strFileToImport As String

'The location of the file you wish to load
strFileToImport = "C:\tmp\test.csv"

intPointer = FreeFile()
Open strFileToImport For Input Access Read Lock Read As #intPointer

intCounter = 1
Do Until EOF(intPointer)
    'Loading row by row from the text file into strLine
    Line Input #intPointer, strLine
    'Check if the "KeyYouAreLookingFor" can be found in that line
    '... if it can be found then copy it to the first sheet
    If InStr(1, strLine, "KeyYouAreLookingFor") Then
        Worksheets(1).Cells(intCounter + 1, 1).Value2 = strLine
        intCounter = intCounter + 1
    Else
        'If the key cannot be found but has been found in the past
        '... then (following your logic that the file is sorted)
        '... all other rows in the file can be ignored and
        '... the import is complete: so the program should stop
        If intCounter > 1 Then Exit Sub
    End If
Loop

Close intPointer

End Sub
```

Have a look at the comments in the code for more explanations and let me know if this suits your needs.

Assuming that you 50MB text file is a `,` delimited `CSV` file you could further more refine the above code like so:

```
If InStr(1, Split(strLine, ",")(0), "KeyYouAreLookingFor") Then
```

Of course, this assumes that your "Key" is within the first column of each row. If not, just make the proper adjustments to your liking.

Comment: Hi Ralph, thanks for the quick response. The way I would want it to work is to start in the middle, and if the key is greater than the one found in the middle, disregard everything above it, then find the middle of the remaining half of the file >rinse and repeat till the key has been found. If that isn't possible then that is ok. Just thought I would ask the question.      Just a quick question about your code - would the solution above be faster than "textfile.readall" and then looking through each line to find the data required?

Comment: Short answer: the above solution is the best if you are dealing with large files (such as yours). With most text editors you cannot even open large text files (100MB or bigger). Just give it a try with NotePad and you will see. The above code is best because it reads line by line into memory only. **Not** the entire file at once. I have handled with the above code even files >500MB without problems. Your proposition would be valid if there would be a tool out there that supports that. But even the usage of an ODBC connect with a `SELECT` would require the **entire** file to scan.

Comment: Hi Ralph, I just tried your solution, it took around two/three minutes to execute line "Line Input #intPointer, strLine" I assume that's when excel is accessing the entire file on the server and downloading it. Just to give you an idea of how slow it is, during the "download" my Lan connection was only 1% utilised(of 100mbps).

Comment: If possible, try do download the file locally and then execute the code (for comparison). You'll see that it will execute much faster. The difference is merely Windows inefficient way of handling remote files (as opposed to local file). At least the above solution stops once the key has been passed (doesn't look any further). Your "wish" to also read nothing "before" the key is (to my knowledge) not possible while maintaining the speed of the above code.

Comment: I'd vote to close / accept this question unless you can think of any possible mean to outperform this solution (using Excel). If the performance of this solution is not satisfactory then you might want to think about using database servers (such as MS SQL or MySQL) to host the information contained in that file (rather than a file server).

Comment: Thanks Ralph, much appreciated.